# Is there a possibility to import a KERAS model to Matlab without the Deep Learning Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, keras, import, export

I have worked out a LSTM model and would like to incorporate it into a MATLAB framework. Via the Deep Learning Toolbox the functions **importKerasLayers** and **importKerasNetwork** can be called.

Is there also a way to implement the model without the Deep Learning Toolbox?

Answer (score -1):

With a new version of MATLAB, it is possible to invoke Python from MATLAB. Check this URL https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/create-object-from-python-class.html#mw_c224a09a-f56b-48e5-b9ec-145388506204

I'm not sure, what you are trying to achieve by importing keras inside MATLAB. I guess, you may want to use MATLAB for your data preprocessing activities. If that is the case, you may complete preprocessing separately and save data in to numpy or pandas format to consume from Python.

Comment: I think I phrased my question a bit woolly. The LSTM is already trained and delivers good results. Now, after exporting it in 'h5' format, I would like to import it into a Matlab model. Is there any way to do this without using the functions from the deep learning toolbox?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to load H5 model without deep learning toolbox. Unless you find any equivalent functions from MATLAB central,